# API data in kotlin fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

I am trying to use `Drawer activity`, seems that it has 3 files to just show simple text as `This is home Fragment` :|

Anyway, I have tracked back all those files and found `fragment_home.xml`, `HomeFragment.kt` and `HomeViewModel.kt`

> ## Question
>
> **How should I call for API data trough fragments?**

## Code

`my code`

Based on [android studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple) this is the code that I should use in order to get my api data.

```
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.TextView)

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
val url = "https://example.com/api/listings"

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
val stringRequest = StringRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, url,
    Response.Listener<String> { response ->
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        textView.text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}"
    },
    Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "That didn't work!" })

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest)
```

> PS: I have tried this code above in empty activity it's working

`HomeViewModel.kt`

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _text = MutableLiveData<String>().apply {
        value = "This is home Fragment"
    }
    val text: LiveData<String> = _text
}
```

`HomeFragment.kt`

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
        homeViewModel.text.observe(this, Observer {
            textView.text = it
        })
        return root
    }
}
```

`fragment_home.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> **Please note, before you try to give down-vote:** I am aware this question probably is very basic question, but note that it's my first
>   time ever using fragments (basically newbie in android studio), so yes
>   my questions are kind of basic :)

Comment: @AshwiniViolet I already done it in activity so i know that, but since my new app by default is using fragments i thought i should use these fragments but with my version of data instead of static text :)

Comment: Just some extra :- A `Fragment` is also a part of `Activity`. Activity is like a "Blackboard" and everything like view, fragments etc.  all are words on this black board.

Comment: @AshwiniViolet yes i was just reading about it, it's more like module in node, or services in angular can share data in any activity (i get that) but i need to get data in this fragment first then think about sharing this data in which activity right? :))

Comment: let me write the code in answer, but i'm not confident what problem you actually facing. so i'll edit it based on your feedback

Comment: check my answer now, only difference will be `val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)`. as i told you a fragment implement over activity, so we passing the `context` of `activity` on which the fragment is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for calling the API from fragment, you can do

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

  private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

            override fun onCreateView(
                inflater: LayoutInflater,
                container: ViewGroup?,
                savedInstanceState: Bundle?
            ): View? {
                homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

                val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

                val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)

                //calling the API
                callAPIDemo(textView)

               // homeViewModel.text.observe(this, Observer {
               //     textView.text = it
               // })

                return root
            }

     fun callAPIDemo(textView: TextView) {
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)
        val url = "https://example.com/api/listings"

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, url,
                Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                    textView.text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}"
                },
                Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "That didn't work!" })

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest)
    }

        }
```

Comment: i did change it, i was aware of that part

Comment: i am, in browser your url and my real url both returning data

Comment: hold on :)) i think i forgot add internet permission

Comment: ah! yes that was it, sorry :)

Comment: may i ask you 1 more thing?

Comment: currently my data are returning based on element `id` here `R.id.text_home` how can i make loop of my data? let say having columns of my data images or cards etc.?

Comment: like Gmail show list of emails? that's how you asking?

Comment: something like that yes

Comment: more like this https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSlp6NTkNfRmL2MbVO4WPNsC8ii6HuKrllV-S6dn3c3Pb87dS0Y

Comment: for that purpose we have a `ListView`(old but easy to use, not recommended in real project) and `RecyclerView` (the best one)

Comment: if you look closely in the image you showing, the 4 card is actually  same but only have different attributes (like color, image and data value )

Comment: yes, i mean having scroll page so my items are like that each row has it's own card (image, text, etc.)

Comment: you don't need to create each card by yourself. you create a sample card and `RecyclerView`  take care of rendering it multiple time

Comment: that's exactly my intention, that's why i said making loop

Comment: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html
check this tutorial of `ListView`, remember `ListView` is now not used much, but it will provide you a really basic understanding

Comment: happy to help you!

Comment: made new question due to confusion :D  would you mind to check it please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105586/how-to-use-recyclerview-in-kotlin