# How to use RecyclerView in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Previously I have asked about [calling API in fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60096397/api-data-in-kotlin-fragment) and now that I have my data returning in my app I would like to know **how to make `RecyclerView` in this fragments?**

Basically this is what i'm looking for to achieve at the end

[image: one]

## Code

`HomeFragment.kt`

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)

        //calling the API
        callAPIDemo(textView)

        // homeViewModel.text.observe(this, Observer {
        //     textView.text = it
        // })

        return root
    }

    fun callAPIDemo(textView: TextView) {
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)
        val url = "https://example.com/api/listings"

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                textView.text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}"
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "Something is wrong!" })

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest)
    }

}
```

`fragment_home.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is all i have at the moment.

> Please note that I'm newbie in this, giving help with little bit of detailed explanation is much appreciated.

## Update

Here is what I've created so far

`HomeFragment.kt`

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.recycler)

        //calling the API
        //callAPIDemo(textView)

        val adapter = RecyclerAdapter(callAPIDemo(textView))
        recycler.adapter = adapter

        return root
    }

    fun callAPIDemo(textView: TextView) {
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)
        val url = "https://example.com/api/listings"

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                // Display the response.
                textView.text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0)}"
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "Something is wrong!" })

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest)
    }

}
```

`ListingAdapter.kt`

This class is red and returning error of

> Parameters must have type annotation

```
class RecyclerAdapter(List) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>() {

    //Binding data for each tile
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
    }

    //Creation of view holder for each tile
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        context = parent.context  //this context is red
        return RecyclerViewHolder(inflater, parent)
    }

    //View Holder for each item in recycler
    inner class RecyclerViewHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.listings_layout, parent, false)) {
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

`listings_layout.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="195dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/Image"
                    android:scaleType="matrix" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/MakeUp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewSlug"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/MakeUp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />


            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And finally my `fragment_home.xml`

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler" />
```

Comment: It's just like using a RecyclerView in Java.  Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: @RyanMentley i'm completely newbie in this as i mentioned in last line, i don't have any experience with `RecyclerView` in java nor kotlin. (it's my first time :) )

Comment: Have you done any research?  What have you tried?

Comment: @RyanMentley yes i have tried 2 ways `1` was with creating `RecyclerView` from `file > new` which gave me 2 kotlin files and i had to make extra `xml` file for items, and other one was adding `changeView` after `onCreate` something like that...

Comment: A RecyclerView have 3 parts. 1 is the view it self to show listing (we define it in the xml of our fragment/activity). 2nd is a layout file (a sample layout file about how the list will look, as you show in image). 3rd is the adapter, who  is responsible for holding your data and binding them with the view

Comment: @AshwiniViolet updated my question would you check it now please?

Comment: I was actually creating a detailed answer. Just few minutes more and I'll post it, but it's based on your older question not on update

Comment: Sorry for a long answer, i tried to explain the whole process and how it's working, i'll update or add more info based on your queries

Comment: @AshwiniViolet actually i'm very much appreciate your long answer <3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You will need to create a layout for how a single row in your list will look(considering we are creating horizontal listing)

navigate to res > layout folder in your project, in layout folder create a Layout Resource File (fancy name, but it's just a XML file)

**for example:-**

**layout_demo_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/a_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/a_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/a_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/a_image" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_random"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text_title" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Second you need an Adapter.

An Adapter will take a list/array of data from you, render number of rows based on size of list and assign the data to each row based on position on list

**for example:-**

You have an array of 6 names, then the adapter will create 6 identical row based on `layout_demo_item.xml` and assign data like 0th position data in array will be assigned to first element of list

**MyAdapter.kt**

```
    class MyAdapter(var dataList: MutableList<DataModelObject>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {


        // inflating a layout in simple word is way of using a xml layout inside a class.
        // if you look this is the same thing that your fragment doing inside onCreateView and storing that into "root" variable, we just did that in "view"
        // we passed "view" to MyViewHolder and returned an object of MyViewHolder class(this object actually a single row without data)
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_demo_item, parent, false)

            return MyViewHolder(view)
        }


        //the returned object of MyViewHolder class will come here and also with the position on which it gonna show,
        // now based on this position we can get the value from our list and finally set it to the corresponding view that we have here in variable "holder"
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

            holder.textView.text = dataList.get(position).title
            holder.textViewRandom.text = dataList.get(position).randomText

            //hardcoding the image, just for simplicity, you can set this also from data list same as above
            holder.aImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)


   //here is the image setup by using glide
 //Glide.with(holder.aImage.context).load(dataList.get(position).image).into(holder.aImage)

        }

        // this method telling adapter to how many total rows will be rendered based on count, so we returning the size of list that we passing
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return dataList.size
        }


        // while creating the object in onCreateViewHolder, we received "view" here, and as you can see in your fragment,
        // we can do find views by id on it same as we doing in fragment
        // so your MyViewHolder now hold the reference of the actual views, on which you will set data
        class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


            var textView: TextView
            var textViewRandom: TextView
            var aImage: ImageView


            init {

                textViewRandom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_random)
                textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_title)
                aImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.a_image)

            }

        }
    }
```

here is the data class that we using as our model class(same as a `POJO` class in `Java` but it's just in `Kotlin`)

```
  data class DataModelObject(var randomText:String,var title :String) {
    }
```

We have all things set to create a `recyclerView`, so now we will define `recyclerView` in Fragment like

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_home" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Finally Inside kotlin class setting up a `recyclerView`

**HomeFragment.kt**

(i'm not including the irrelevant methods and variable that you have in this fragment, please consider them)

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {



        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_home)

        callAPIDemo(textView)

        setUpRecyclerView(recyclerView);


        return root
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {

        // first our data list that can come from API/Database
        // for now i'm just manually creating the list in getDummyData()
        val list: MutableList<DataModelObject> = getDummyData()

        // created an adapter object by passing the list object
        var myAdapter = MyAdapter(list)

        //it's a layoutManager, that we use to tell recyclerview in which fashion  we want to show list,
        // default is vertical even if you don't pass it and just pass the activity , and we don't want to reversing it so false
        // by customizing it you can create Grids,vertical and horizontal lists, even card swipe like tinder
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)




        // just set the above layout manager on RecyclerView
        recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

        //and give it a adapter for data
        recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter


    }



    private fun getDummyData(): MutableList<DataModelObject> {

        val list: MutableList<DataModelObject> = mutableListOf(

                DataModelObject("dfgdfg", "title 1"),
                DataModelObject("tyuityui", "title 2"),
                DataModelObject("yuti", "title 3"),
                DataModelObject("uY9NOrc-=s180-rw", "title 4"),
                DataModelObject("logo_color_272x92dp.png", "title 5"),
                DataModelObject("NOVtP26EKH", "title 6"),
                DataModelObject("googlelogo_color", "title 7"),
                DataModelObject("sNOVtP26EKHePkwBg-PkuY9NOrc-", "title 8")

        )

        return list

    }

}
```

Comment: i have error for this part `val list: MutableList<Listing> = getDummyData()` would you mind show me how we can get data from api? currently `callAPIDemo` is returning api data so maybe you can use it here?

Comment: also I removed `val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)` this text view i don't use any more just my list cards in this page.

Comment: actually previously i forgot to add this data class in answer, you need to create a class like this in your project, just create a kotlin class `data class DataModelObject(var randomText:String,var title :String) {
    }`

Comment: i already created class with this values `data class Listing(
    val title: String,
    val slug: String,
    val image: Matrix,
    val isNew: Boolean
)`

Comment: are you able to run it with the data class that i provided?  just to make sure it's properly working for you, then i'll explain how you can do it by your API calling

Comment: can you please  check in your logcat and show me the error

Comment: oh fixed now :) it was this part `val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.recycler)` forgot to comment it as i was removed the element in xml file

Comment: In side your home fragment, it seems you defined recyclerview as a text view.. Please check that you properly did find view by id and storing it in the recycleview type variable

Comment: okay run and check if you can see the list that we created. and please also read the comments that i left on code to understand the working

Comment: ok, i've read all comments twice :D and now there is 3 questions left for me there.  `1` How do I replace my online data with dummy ones `2` should I add `image` in class like this? https://ibb.co/H2sJjwL  `3` about getting dynamic image in adapter `holder.aImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)` when i tried like this `holder.aImage.setImageResource(dataList.get(position).image)` the image part was red.

Comment: let's move this into chat so i can explain you these

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207410/discussion-between-ashwini-violet-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 0):

At first create a single item xml for each item of your recycler.

Then add the recycler in your fragment xml:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

Then create an adapter class as shown below:

```
class RecyclerAdapter(List) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>() {

    //Binding data for each tile
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
    }

    //Creation of view holder for each tile
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        context = parent.context
        return RecyclerViewHolder(inflater, parent)
    }

    //View Holder for each item in recycler
    inner class RecyclerViewHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false)) {
        }

}
```

Then use the adapter like below in fragment:

```
val adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(List)
recyclerview.adapter = adapter
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i get this in adapter `: Parameters must have type annotation` also `context = parent.context` is red